# Python3 - last character of the string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I want to get the last character of the string.
I can print it using `len` method to get it BUT I can't compare it to another character while getting it using the VERY SAME method. Now I'll just paste this **WTF** code here. Please tell me what's going on here.

```
fields = line.split(';')
last = fields[0]
capacity = fields[1]
region = fields[2]

print(capacity)
print('kek')
print(capacity[len(capacity)-1])
print('even more kek')
while capacity[len(capacity)-1] == '0':
    capacity = capacity[1:len(capacity)-2]
    last = last[1:len(last)-2]
```

Now, the output

```
100000
kek
0
even more kek
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mekkanizer/Документы/proj/rossvyaz/making_insert_queries.py", line 52, in <module>
    while capacity[len(capacity)-1] == '0':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `capacity[-1]`? Also, note what happens when `len(capacity) == 0`; `''[-1]` isn't going to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ended up with an empty string, so there is nothing to index anymore:

```
>>> ''[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

You do so by shortening `capacity` in the `while` loop:

```
capacity = capacity[1:len(capacity)-2]
```

You start with `100000`, then make that `'000'`, then `''`:

```
>>> capacity = '100000'
>>> capacity[1:len(capacity)-2]
'000'
>>> capacity[1:len(capacity)-2][1:len(capacity)-2]
''
```

You may have missed you are doing this as you are never printing the value of `capacity` *in the loop*.

You can always index *from the end* using negative indices:

```
>>> 'last character'[-1]
'r'
```

This works for slicing too:

```
>>> 'last character'[5:-4]
'chara'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the method with negative indices BUT please explain how did I end with an empty string if I actuallly CAN print it's last character one line of code before and I do NOT change the string anyhow.

Comment: @mekkanizer: you do change the value of `capacity`. In the loop you assign it to `capacity[1:len(capacity)-2]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mekkanizer/Документы/proj/rossvyaz/making_insert_queries.py", line 52, in <module>
    while capacity[len(capacity)-1] == '0':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

The only case in which this would happen is when `capacity` is an empty string, and `len(capacity)-1` is therefore `-1`, which is not a valid index into an empty string.

This does not happen during the first iteration of the loop (you've checked for that), but evidently does happen during a subsequent iteration, after you've shortened `capacity`.

My advice would be to read up on Python's slicing notation, in particular using negative indices to refer to the end of the string. One good resource is [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the method with negative indices BUT please explain how did I end with an empty string if I actuallly CAN print it's last character one line of code before and I do NOT change the string anyhow.

Comment: @mekkanizer: You print it *before* the loop, but then change it *inside* the loop.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can get items numbered from the end of a sequence by using a negative index. Correspondingly, the *last* item has the index -1. That is, your construct `capacity[1:len(capacity)-2]` is not needed at all. The others have pointed out what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing notation which will return "" for an empty string:

```
while capacity[len(capacity)-1:] == 0
```

Or use while capacity to catch empty strings:

```
while capacity and capacity[-1] == "0":
```

You keep shortening capacity when reassigning `capacity`  in your while loop so eventually it will be an empty string:

```
 capacity = capacity[1:len(capacity)-2] 

foobar foobar <- start
oobar foob <- first iteration
obar fo <- second iteration
bar  <- third iterations
a <- fourth iteration
empty string == index error
```